# yum trying to install el5 when I am on el6

Tags: yum, rpm, rhel6

When I run the following yum command I get this error:

```
Package: git-1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)"
```

I read that this error is due to running an el5 rpmforge or having some el5 installed packages.

How can I solve this problem?

```
$ yum install git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.kiewel-online.ch
 * epel: fedora.kiewel-online.ch
 * extras: centos.kiewel-online.ch
 * rpmforge: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * updates: centos.kiewel-online.ch
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf for package: git-1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexpat.so.0()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package compat-expat1.x86_64 0:1.95.8-8.el6 will be installed
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64
---> Package perl-Git.x86_64 0:1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: git-1.7.10.1-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `yum repolist` to show which repos you have enabled, and hence where the package is coming from;

(also `yum repolist -v`, with the `-v` flag for really verbose description of your enabled repositories)

```
# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                    |  10 kB     00:00     
 * base: mirrors.usc.edu
 * epel: epel.mirror.freedomvoice.com
 * extras: mirrors.usc.edu
 * updates: mirrors.usc.edu
Webmin                           | 1.2 kB     00:00     
base                             | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                           | 3.5 kB     00:00     
rbel6                            | 1.9 kB     00:00     
updates                          | 3.5 kB     00:00     
repo id            repo                                              status
Webmin             Webmin Distribution Neutral                       174+1
base               CentOS-6 - Base                                   6,293+1
epel               Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64    7,345
extras             CentOS-6 - Extras                                  4
rbel6              RBEL 6 Repo                                       183
updates            CentOS-6 - Updates                                921+6
repolist: 14,920
```

and also to show which repositories support the packages for your requirement;

```
# yum provides git
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.usc.edu
 * epel: epel.mirror.freedomvoice.com
 * extras: mirrors.usc.edu
 * updates: mirrors.usc.edu
git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64 : Fast Version Control System
Repo        : base
Matched from:

git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64 : Fast Version Control System        
Repo        : installed 

Matched from:               
Other       : Provides-match: git
```

Comment: Thanks yes, it was an issue with rpmrepos, although meanwhileI found another quick and similar solution here https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=33231&forum=56&post_id=142385
"Just enabled the rpmforge extras repo - it found the el6, job don - all installed."

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem under CentOS 6.3.  Running `yum provides git` gave me two choices:

```
git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64 : Fast Version Control System
git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64 : Fast Version Control System
```

So, I did a `yum install git-1.7.1-2.el6_0.1.x86_64` and it installed the .el6 version of git, along with perl-Error and perl-Git, and issues no errors and no missing libcurl.so files!